# Trouble assigning form field values to separate arrays based on a specific option in elementor forms

Tags: php, hook, elementor

I'm having trouble fetching the value of the attribute in the form field advance tab to compare in an IF statement. I'm attempting to assign field values to separate arrays based on the value of $selected_option, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Could someone please review and help fix the code?

```
if ($selected_option === 'vehicle') {  
     $vehicleFields[] = [$field_name => $field_value];  
 } elseif ($selected_option === 'customer') {  
     $customerFields[] = [$field_name => $field_value];  
 } elseif ($selected_option === 'vendor') {  
     $vendorFields[] = [$field_name => $field_value];  
 }
```

I'm not able to  populate the $vehicleFields, $customerFields, and $vendorFields arrays with the appropriate field values based on the value of $selected_option.

```
<?php
global $selected_option;
class Elementor_Forms_Patterns_Validation {
   // public $selected_option;
    public $allowed_fields = [
        'text',
        'email',
        'textarea',
    ];

    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'elementor_pro/forms/render/item', [ $this, 'maybe_add_attribute' ], 10, 3 );
        add_action( 'elementor/element/form/section_form_fields/before_section_end', [ $this, 'add_attribute_field_control' ], 100, 2 );
    }

    public function add_attribute_field_control( $element, $args ) {
        $elementor = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
        $control_data = $elementor->controls_manager->get_control_from_stack( $element->get_name(), 'form_fields' );

        if ( is_wp_error( $control_data ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $tmp = new \Elementor\Repeater();
        $tmp->add_control(
            'field_attribute',
            [
                'label' => 'Attribute',
                'inner_tab' => 'form_fields_advanced_tab',
                'tab' => 'content',
                'tabs_wrapper' => 'form_fields_tabs',
                'type' => 'select',
                'options' => [
                    '' => 'None',
                    'vehicle' => 'vehicle',
                    'customer' => 'customer',
                    'vendor' => 'vendor',
                ],
                'conditions' => [
                    'terms' => [
                        [
                            'name' => 'field_type',
                            'operator' => 'in',
                            'value' => $this->allowed_fields,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );

        $attribute_field = $tmp->get_controls();
        $attribute_field = $attribute_field['field_attribute'];

        $new_order = [];
        foreach ( $control_data['fields'] as $field_key => $field ) {
            if ( 'custom_id' === $field['name'] ) {
                $new_order['field_attribute'] = $attribute_field;
            }
            $new_order[ $field_key ] = $field;
        }
        $control_data['fields'] = $new_order;

        $element->update_control( 'form_fields', $control_data );
    }
        //echo 'Selected attribute value: ';
                //print_r($selected_options);
          public function maybe_add_attribute( $field, $field_index, $form_widget ) {
        if ( isset( $field['field_attribute'] ) && in_array( $field['field_type'], $this->allowed_fields ) ) {
            $attribute = $field['field_attribute'];
            if ( ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
                $form_widget->add_render_attribute( 'input' . $field_index, 'data-attribute', $attribute );
                // Set the selected option to the global variable
                global $selected_option;
                $selected_option=array();
                $selected_option[] = $attribute;
            }
        }
        return $field;
    }
}

// Convert Elementor form data to ADF format and send email
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $handler ) {
    // Get form data and form name
    $data = $record->get_formatted_data();
    $form_id = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_id' );
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
    
    
    // Create ADF data array dynamically
    $adf_data = array();
    foreach ( $data as $field_name => $field_value ) {
        // Replace any space in field name with underscore
        $field_name = str_replace( ' ', '_', $field_name );
        $adf_data[ $field_name ] = $field_value;
    }

    // Generate ADF XML
    $xml = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "UTF-8" );
    $adf = $xml->createElement( "adf" );
    $prospect = $xml->createElement( "prospect" );

    // Add request date to prospect
    $requestdate = $xml->createElement( "requestdate", date( 'c' ) );
    $prospect->appendChild( $requestdate );
  

    global $selected_option;

    $vehicleFields = [];
    $customerFields = [];
    $vendorFields = [];
    
    
        if ( $selected_option === 'vehicle' ) 
        {
        $vehicleFields[] = [$field_name => $field_value];
        } 
        
        elseif ( $selected_option === 'customer' ) 
        {
        $customerFields[] = [$field_name => $field_value];
        } 
        
        elseif ( $selected_option === 'vendor' ) 
        {
        $vendorFields[] = [$field_name => $field_value];
        }

    
// Add vehicle data to prospect
if ( ! empty( $vehicleFields ) ) {
    $vehicle = $xml->createElement( "vehicle" );
    foreach ( $vehicleFields as $field ) {
        foreach ( $field as $field_name => $field_value ) {
            $fieldElement = $xml->createElement( $field_name, $field_value );
            $vehicle->appendChild( $fieldElement );
        }
    }
    $prospect->appendChild( $vehicle );
}
// Add customer data to prospect
if ( ! empty( $customerFields ) ) {
    $customer = $xml->createElement( "customer" );
    $contact = $xml->createElement( "contact" );
    foreach ( $customerFields as $field ) {
        foreach ( $field as $field_name => $field_value ) {
            $fieldElement = $xml->createElement( $field_name, $field_value );
            $contact->appendChild( $fieldElement );
        }
    }
    $customer->appendChild( $contact );
    $prospect->appendChild( $customer );
}

// Add vendor data to prospect
if ( ! empty( $vendorFields ) ) {
    $vendor = $xml->createElement( "vendor" );
    $contact = $xml->createElement( "contact" );
    foreach ( $vendorFields as $field ) {
        foreach ( $field as $field_name => $field_value ) {
            $fieldElement = $xml->createElement( $field_name, $field_value );
            $contact->appendChild( $fieldElement );
        }
    }
    $vendor->appendChild( $contact );
    $prospect->appendChild( $vendor );
}

    $adf->appendChild( $prospect );
    $xml->appendChild( $adf );

    // Format ADF XML for readability
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $adf_xml = $xml->saveXML();

    // Send email with ADF XML in body
    $to = array( 'example@mail.com')
    $subject = 'Subject ';
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
        'From: From <email@example.com>
    );
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $adf_xml, $headers );
}, 10, 2 );

new Elementor_Forms_Patterns_Validation();
```

> Expectation
>
> For Example
> Model=Blazer
> Name=John Doe
> phone=393-999-3922
>
> if Model is selected as Vehicle
> if Name is selected as customer
> if Phone is selected as Vendor
> Output should be like that

EXPECTED OUTPUT
[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

ACTUAL OUTPUT
[image: ACTUAL OUTPUT]

Comment: The repeated use of the `global` immediately raises some red flags. Why are you doing that? Just pass it to the function. Would rewrite the code so that you are not using a global - definitely not defining it three times and at differing scopes.

Comment: I am only able to fetch the value of attribute "$attribute = $field['field_attribute'];" in  
public function maybe_add_attribute(). I am unable to fetch it in other functions maybe because it is rendered in that function <br>
$form_widget->add_render_attribute( 'input' . $field_index, 'data-attribute', $attribute );<br>
Thats why I am using Global<br>
can you tell me how can I fetch "$attribute = $field['field_attribute'];" directly in this function add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $handler ) {}